# Possible options for hosting static website on azure storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I have a simple static web page (one html file) which i have hosted onto my storage blob container (via static website option).
My storage has network firewall configured to "Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses" option.

As per documentation (MSDN); firewall settings as said above will also block traffic for the static website container/blobs, So no body around the globe can access my static website without whitelisting their public IP.

**I am not allowed to change the firewall settings for many reasons.**
Neither i can configure all the public IP addresses for all my users around a region (continent) (not practically possible)

The possible options i can think off is:

1. CDN combination with the storage => Not a solution for my needs as cost is lil high. Neither i need all CDN benefits too.
2. Host webpage via AppService or Static WebApps services of Azure => Again too much for a simple web page (one html file with CSS)
3. Create another storage account with a full public network firewall access and host the website there and make sure no other sensitive data resides in this account

Kindly please suggest on the possible solutions.

Thanks

Note: I have searched enough on stackoverflow/google/github. No luck finding any answers.

Comment: I would go for option 3. Storage Account is either for local use only or for public use only. It's very cheap (pretty much free) to create a new storage account. That's the beauty of cloud: everything can be separated and managed in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need custom domain and ssl, I'd go Static Web Apps.
If you don't care what the domain is, I'd go with a new dedicated storage account.l with the Web option.